# MySQL calculating negative value on INT UNSIGNED

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `start_date_time INT UNSIGNED` column in my table.

I have a query like this

```
... WHERE (g.start_date_time-$currentTime) > 0 ORDER BY (g.start_date_time-$currentTime)
```

And I get an error `Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in...`. If I set it to **SIGNED** of course everything works, but my question is is there a way to keep it **UNSIGNED** but anyway calculate negative values (I need just calculation, don't need to store them anywhere), or I should redefine my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should redefine as following

```
WHERE g.start_date_time > $currentTime ORDER BY g.start_date_time
```

This will allow using indexes on g.start_date_time column and you don't have to order by (g.start_date_time-$currentTime)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` to cast them to signed integers for your calculation. However, if you have anything larger than a signed integer in there you will get undesired results. You shouldn't be using integers for timestamps anyways. Use a timestamp or datetime field.